# Back Projection in Java with OpenCV

Tags: java, android, opencv, image-processing

I want to detect features in an image with [OpenCV](http://opencv.org/) using back projection.

For a start I would be very happy to compute a histogram of a single colored small image and then apply it on a larger image. Then I can build more on top of that.
There is a [example in C++](http://code.opencv.org/projects/opencv/repository/revisions/master/raw/samples/cpp/tutorial_code/Histograms_Matching/calcBackProject_Demo2.cpp) and I would like to do something like this in Java.
Sadly, the Java interface to OpenCV is not very well documented.

Below is the code I have so far, but it is not working (obviously, else I wouldn't ask for help).
It would be very great if someone could **help me get it working** or **find some good documentation** for the Java API!

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import org.opencv.core.*;
import org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc;

public class ColorHistogramDetector extends ColorThresholdDetector {
    //private cvHistogram histogram;
    //histogram resolution for hue and saturation
    static final int hbins = 30;//, sbins = 32;

    public synchronized Mat detect(Mat inputFrame) {
        Mat calcFrame = new Mat();
        Imgproc.cvtColor(inputFrame, calcFrame, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2HSV);

        Mat hue = calcFrame;
        ArrayList<Mat> dst = new ArrayList<Mat>();
        dst.add(hue);

        //create single color image
        Mat fillImg = new Mat(16, 16, CvType.CV_8UC3);
        fillImg.setTo(hsvColor);

        MatOfInt histSize=new MatOfInt(hbins,hbins);

        // hue varies from 0 to 179, see cvtColor
        // saturation varies from 0 (black-gray-white) to
        // 255 (pure spectrum color)
        MatOfFloat ranges = new MatOfFloat( 0,180,0,256 );

        Mat hist = new Mat();

        // we compute the histogram from the 0-th and 1-st channels
        MatOfInt channels = new MatOfInt(0, 1);

        ArrayList<Mat> fillImgs=new ArrayList<Mat>();
        fillImgs.add(fillImg);
        Imgproc.calcHist(fillImgs, channels, new Mat(), hist, histSize, ranges);

        outputFrame = new Mat();

        Imgproc.calcBackProject(dst, channels, hist, calcFrame, ranges, 1);

        int w = inputFrame.cols(); int h = inputFrame.rows();
        int bin_w = (int) Math.round( (double) w / hbins );
        Mat histImg = new Mat( w, h, CvType.CV_8UC3 );

        for( int i = 0; i < hbins; i ++ ) { 
           Core.rectangle( histImg, new Point( i*bin_w, h ), 
                           new Point( (i+1)*bin_w, 
                           h - Math.round( hist.get(0, i)[0]*h/255.0 ) ), 
                           new Scalar( 0, 0, 255 ), -1 ); 
        }

        hist.release();
        fillImg.release();

        Imgproc.cvtColor(histImg, calcFrame, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2HSV);

        return calcFrame;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is it not working?  Are you getting an error, or are the results different from what you expect?

Comment: The resulting frame is always empty (filled with 0)

Comment: You don't seem to have `normalize(...)` between `calcHist` and `calcBackProject`. How does the content of `hist` look like? It is of type 8UC1 or some float format

Comment: The Java API is automatically generated from the C++ headers. You can find the documentation here: http://docs.opencv.org/java/

Comment: yes, but that doesn't help with the usage of functions which take pointers in C++! How do I use them in Java?

Comment: It would really help if you style your code from time to time... Not just for the developer that's reading it, but for you to debug your code more easily. (work more on the indenting!)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Several things look odd in your code so my advice for you is to first follow the tutorial closely and then change it to your use-case.

You seem somehow close to the tutorial you are following but it looks like you are applying `calcHist` to a single colored image. I do not see how that is useful, it should typically be a HSV image with some object(s) instead. Also, you are missing the `normalize` step.

To help you with that I have converted that [C++ Back Projection Tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/back_projection/back_projection.html#back-projection)  to OpenCV4Android 2.4.8.

**Although you are using Java instead of Android, the API is the exactly the same, only boilerplate input/output handling will differ.**

[Original C++ code can be found here.](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/tree/master/samples/cpp/tutorial_code/Histograms_Matching/calcBackProject_Demo2.cpp)

Made some very minor changes to the original tutorial to make it more usable for Android, for example:

- it processes the live camera image, instead of static images;
- uses touch events to replace the mouse click;
- the output of the back-projection is displayed at the top left corner overlaying the camera feed;
- added Gaussian blur as noise reduction.

[image: Back Projection Screenshot]

I have not yet tested all the steps thoroughly but the end result looks ok.

Note: as it stands, you need to touch the screen once to initialize the Back Projection...

Here is most of it, what is missing you can find [here at GitHub](https://github.com/ruimarques/OpenCV.git):

```
private int outputWidth=300;
private int outputHeight=200;
private Mat mOutputROI;

private boolean bpUpdated = false;

private Mat mRgba;
private Mat mHSV;
private Mat mask;

private int lo = 20; 
private int up = 20;

public void onCameraViewStarted(int width, int height) {

    mRgba = new Mat(height, width, CvType.CV_8UC3);
    mHSV = new Mat();
    mIntermediateMat = new Mat();
    mGray = new Mat(height, width, CvType.CV_8UC1);
    mOutputROI = new Mat(outputHeight, outputWidth, CvType.CV_8UC1);

    mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);        
}

public Mat onCameraFrame(CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
    Mat mCamera = inputFrame.rgba();

    Imgproc.cvtColor(mCamera, mRgba, Imgproc.COLOR_RGBA2RGB);

    Mat mOutputROI = mCamera.submat(0, outputHeight, 0, outputWidth);

    //Addition to remove some noise:
    Imgproc.GaussianBlur(mRgba, mRgba, new Size(5, 5), 0, Imgproc.BORDER_DEFAULT);

    Imgproc.cvtColor(mRgba, mHSV, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2HSV_FULL);

    if(mask!=null){
        if(bpUpdated==false){
            mGray = histAndBackproj();
        } else {
            bpUpdated = false;
        }

        Imgproc.resize(mGray, mIntermediateMat, mOutputROI.size(), 0, 0, Imgproc.INTER_LINEAR);
        Imgproc.cvtColor(mIntermediateMat, mOutputROI, Imgproc.COLOR_GRAY2BGRA);
    }

    return mCamera;
}

public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {       
    Point seed = getImageCoordinates(mRgba, arg1.getX(), arg1.getY());

    int newMaskVal = 255;
    Scalar newVal = new Scalar( 120, 120, 120 );

    int connectivity = 8;
    int flags = connectivity + (newMaskVal << 8 ) + Imgproc.FLOODFILL_FIXED_RANGE + Imgproc.FLOODFILL_MASK_ONLY;

    Mat mask2 = Mat.zeros( mRgba.rows() + 2, mRgba.cols() + 2, CvType.CV_8UC1 );

    Rect rect = null;
    Imgproc.floodFill( mRgba, mask2, seed, newVal, rect, new Scalar( lo, lo, lo ), new Scalar( up, up, up), flags );

    // C++: 
    // mask = mask2( new Range( 1, mask2.rows() - 1 ), new Range( 1, mask2.cols() - 1 ) );
    mask = mask2.submat(new Range( 1, mask2.rows() - 1 ), new Range( 1, mask2.cols() - 1 ));

    mGray = histAndBackproj();
    bpUpdated = true;           

    return true;
}

  private Mat histAndBackproj() {
    Mat hist = new Mat();
    int h_bins = 30; 
    int s_bins = 32;

    // C++:
    //int histSize[] = { h_bins, s_bins };
    MatOfInt mHistSize = new MatOfInt (h_bins, s_bins);

    // C++:
    //float h_range[] = { 0, 179 };
    //float s_range[] = { 0, 255 };     
    //const float* ranges[] = { h_range, s_range };     
    //int channels[] = { 0, 1 };

    MatOfFloat mRanges = new MatOfFloat(0, 179, 0, 255);
    MatOfInt mChannels = new MatOfInt(0, 1);

    // C++:
    // calcHist( &hsv, 1, channels, mask, hist, 2, histSize, ranges, true, false );

    boolean accumulate = false;
    Imgproc.calcHist(Arrays.asList(mHSV), mChannels, mask, hist, mHistSize, mRanges, accumulate);

    // C++:
    // normalize( hist, hist, 0, 255, NORM_MINMAX, -1, Mat() );        
    Core.normalize(hist, hist, 0, 255, Core.NORM_MINMAX, -1, new Mat());

    // C++:
    // calcBackProject( &hsv, 1, channels, hist, backproj, ranges, 1, true );        
    Mat backproj = new Mat();
    Imgproc.calcBackProject(Arrays.asList(mHSV), mChannels, hist, backproj, mRanges, 1);

    return backproj;
}


/**
 * Method to scale screen coordinates to image coordinates, 
 * as they have different resolutions.
 * 
 * x - width; y - height; 
 * Nexus 4: xMax = 1196; yMax = 768
 * 
 * @param displayX
 * @param displayY
 * @return
 */
private Point getImageCoordinates(Mat image, float displayX, float displayY){
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();       
    android.graphics.Point outSize = new android.graphics.Point();
    display.getSize(outSize);

    float xScale = outSize.x / (float) image.width();
    float yScale = outSize.y / (float) image.height();                  

    return new Point(displayX/xScale, displayY/yScale);
}
```

Comment: I don't think I can +1 this enough.

Comment: Awesome comment! I haven't done anything with OpenCV in a long time, but because of this I will take a look again :) My original Problem was on Android too, btw.

Answer (score 1):

use [javaCV](https://code.google.com/p/javacv/)(a java interface to openCV). it uses same method convention as of openCV and having lots of example to work with it.